# Usage of reason being

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-order, commas

Most of the times, I have seen that 'reason being' is used in the middle of a sentence with a fixed expression 'the reason being is that'. As reason being is similar to 'because', can we use it in the starting of a sentence? Consider this sentence :

> *For non-living things, the apostrophe + s is not used. Reason being, non-living things cannot own things.*

> *For non-living things, the apostrophe + s is not used. The reason being, non-living things cannot own things.*

> *For non-living things, the apostrophe + s is not used, the reason being is that non-living things cannot own things.*

Which ones are correct among these examples. I am also confused that do we need to use 'the' before 'reason being' when we use it to start a new sentence and is the comma usage correct in the third sentence?

Comment: _The reason being_ is a standard phrase meaning _the reason [for what I have just said} is..._ It is illogical and incorrect to use _both_ 'being' and 'is', as they are different parts of the same verb. So your second example is the correct one (or, better still, _the reason being that_...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the second example is correct.
You can use any of

The reason being,
The reason is,
Because,

However, I feel that the sentence being used as an example is incorrect.
I would expect to see eg

The car's wheel ...
The aerial's loading coil ...
The mountain's peak.